# Async Spring Controllers vs normal Controllers

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-web

I wanted to analyze the improvement I may see by enabling Async Controllers in Spring Boot over normal controller

So here is my test code. One API returns a Callable and another is normal controller API. Both APIs block for **10secs** simulating a long running task

```
@RequestMapping(value="/api/1",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<String> questions() throws InterruptedException{
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        return Arrays.asList("Question1","Question2");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/api/2",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public Callable<List<String>> questionsAsync(){
        return () -> {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            return Arrays.asList("Question2","Question2");
        };
    }
```

I set up embedded tomcat with this configuration i.e only one tomcat processing thread:

```
server.tomcat.max-threads=1
logging.level.org.springframework=debug
```

**Expectations for /api/1**
Since there is only one tomcat thread, another request will not be entertained untill this is processed after 10secs

**Results:**
Meet expectations

---

**Expectations for /api/2**
Since we are returning a callable immediately, the single tomcat thread should get free to process another request. Callable would internally start a new thread. So if you hit the same api it should also gets accepted.

**Results:**
This is not happening and untill the callable executes completely, no further request is entertained.

**Question**
Why is /api/2 not behaving as expected?

Comment: Tomcat is running a threadpool, you got wrong expectations.

Comment: @RomanC I mentioned in question, i set the tomcat's threadpool to contain  only 1 thread.

Comment: Just to be sure: which kind of "other request" do you submit while the spring thread is sleeping?

Comment: @JBNizet other request is the same api request and its not spring thread, it actually tomcat request processing thread that my question is about.(nio-8082-exec-1)

Comment: Try to add logging and have a look at the threadIds to figure out if the callable is executed in a different thread.

Did you configure a TaskExecutor? Spring MVC recommends to do so otherwise the SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor is used.

Comment: You didn't actualy say how you tested your assertions. It works as expected for me (if I have 4 concurrent consumers I see roughly 4x more throughput with the async controller). I measured it with Apache bench running on a different machine than the server.

Comment: @DaveSyer Thanks.  I tested with curl and I can see /api/2 behave as expected. As mentioned below, its infact an issue with chrome browser

Answer (score 14, accepted):

@DaveSyer is right, /api/2 is actually behaving as expected.

I assume you are testing the behavior with a web browser. At least Firefox and Chrome are preventing multiple simultaneous requests to the same URL. If you open 2 tabs with api/2, the second one will only send a request to the application after the first got the response.

Try testing it with a simple bash script, like:

```
curl localhost/api/2 &
curl localhost/api/2 &
curl localhost/api/2 &
```

It will print 3 responses around the same time.

Comment: You and @DaveSyer are absolutely right! This issue is happening only in browser and not with curl or any http client test tool.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to mention that server.tomcat.max-threads is deprecated since Spring boot 2.3. Now use **server.tomcat.threads.max** in your Spring application.properties. The default is 200.